# Java/android socket.close() is not realized by server

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm having an issue trying to get a java server to realize an (android/java) client has closed a TCP socket connection. I figured when the client calls `close()` on the `socket`, the server would catch an `IOException`, but this is not the case. `t_recv` is a thread that receives from `BufferedReader in`, and `t_send` sends using a `PrintWriter out`. Closing `in` causes a timeout and crash, and closing `out` doesn't really seem to do anything. The `PrintWriter` is created in the contructor of the `t_send` thread, and `BufferedReader` is create in the contructor of the `t_recv` thread. Trying to debug this, I created blank `run()` methods in both threads, and the same behaviour occurs.

An interesting note: the client is an Android application, and whenever the emulator freezes and windows has to force close it, the `IOException` is caught in the server and the "User x.x.x.x left" message is displayed.

Client closing connection:

```
try {
    // t_recv.in.close(); - times out and crashes
    // t_send.out.close(); - appears to do nothing
    socket.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Server waiting for client to disconnect:

```
    for (;;)
    {   
        try {
            while ( (msg = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                response = msg;
                System.out.println(response);
                server.broadcast(response);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("User '" + socket.getInetAddress().toString() + "' left");
            try {
                socket.close();
                out.close();
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(-1);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `in` is a BufferedReader, the error is in this line:

```
    while ( (msg = in.readLine()) == null);
```

That will loop for ever if `in` is currently at the EOF.  It should be:

```
    while ( (msg = in.readLine()) != null);
```

See javadoc for [`BufferedReader.readLine()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29), paying specific attention to the conditions in which it returns `null`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm using `while ( (msg = in.readLine()) == null);` to basically busy-wait until a message is available. I've edited the code slightly to show this. It might be a bit sloppy right now, but it works for continuously receiving messages...

Comment: @Shaun - you've got that wrong.  That's not how readLine works.  Read the javadoc.

Comment: So I should be doing something like `while ( (msg = in.readLine()) != null) { // process }`, and when I disconnect a client socket, `readLine()` should throw a `IOException`? Thanks.

Comment: Okay - I have replaced the code with this. The server still does not know that the client is closing the socket though. Any advice on this? Thanks.

Comment: @Shaun - when I said read the javadoc, I meant for **YOU** to **READ** the javadoc ... not ask a whole bunch of other questions that are plainly answered by javadocs.